Understanding Volatility Clustering: Conditional or Unconditional Variance?
A stylized fact observed in financial time series is volatility clustering. Volatility clustering is commonly described as the fact that large changes in asset prices are followed by large changes, and small changes are followed by small changes, regardless of the direction of the price movements. This results in periods of high volatility being clustered together and periods of low volatility being clustered together.
It is my understanding that this empirical observation lead to the development of models with the goal of describing the evolution of volatility. One of the most successfull is the GARCH(1,1), that models the dynamics of the conditional variance of the returns:
\begin{equation}
r_t = \sigma_t \epsilon_t
\end{equation}
where $ \epsilon_t $ is a Gaussian r.v. with zero mean and unitary variance for all $ t $. While the conditional variance is given by the recursive equation
\begin{equation}
\sigma_t^2 = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 r_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2.
\end{equation}
where $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are parameters to be estimated.
But the way volatility clustering is usually presented it seems to refer to a dependence between unconditional variances rather than conditional ones, or at least it seems more natural to conceptualize volatility clustering in terms of the unconditional variance. How should one think about this stylized fact; in terms of unconditional variance or conditional variance?
This raises other questions:
How can one conclusively determine if the observed volatility clustering is primarily due to a conditional variance rather than an unconditional variance? Is there some test? Are there models that decide to model the unconditional variance rather than the conditional one?

An interesting and thoughtful question.

Hi: It's $\sigma^2_t$ at time $(t-1)$ that is viewed as the conditional variance. It's the $E(r^{2}{t})$ that is viewed as the unconditional variance. The link below explains it way better than I can but the idea is that the $\sigma^2{t}$ is calculated using $\sigma^2_{t-1}$ so it's conditional on the sigma algebra at time $(t-1)$. The unconditional  variance is an expectation so there is no conditioning. https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/~dodso013/fm503/1920/uncond-vari.html

The conditional variance is also an expectation by definition, and that expectation is conditional.

@mlofton My question is on whether volatility clustering should be thought of as an effect on the conditional variance or the unconditional variance of the observations and why.

Hi Monolite: The conditional, $\hat{\sigma}^2_t$ causes the volatility clustering because it's a random variable at time $t$ that depends on itself in the previous period, $\hat{\sigma}^2_{t-1}$.  Therefore, when $\hat{\sigma}^{2}{t-1}$ is large (small), this implies that  $\hat{\sigma}^{2}{t}$ will tend to be large (small) also. The unconditional variance, $E(r^{2}_t)$ is a a constant  because it's an expectation so it can't cause volatility clustering.

I'm pretty sure ( based on memory ) that $\beta$ is positive and between $0$ and $1$ so one doesn't have to worry about it taking on negative values. The stationarity condition is $(\alpha_1 + \beta_1)  <= 1.0$.

One more thing: Not to be pedantic but I would think of volatility clustering as an effect OF the conditional variance rather than On the conditional variance.
